# How to update the rating bar using value of the text view in card view?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-cardview, ratingbar

I did tried to update the rating bar using value of the text view in card view but only updating when first card loaded. For all the other cards in the stack rating bar is note updating after the first card.

Basically rating bar not updating after first card has been swipe.

What can i do?

```
  public void getOppositeSexUsers22() {
        usersDb.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                if (dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue() != null) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("nope").hasChild(currentUId) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("yeps").hasChild(currentUId) && dataSnapshot.child("post").getValue().toString().equals(oppositeUserSex2)) {
                        String profileImageUrl = "default";
                        String oppsiteexperince = "default";

                        Integer score0;
                        Integer score1 = 0;
                        Integer score2 = 0;
                        Integer score3 = 0;
                        Integer score4 = 0;

                        if (dataSnapshot.child("industry").getValue().toString().equals(userJob)) {
                            score1 = 50;
                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.child("salary").getValue().toString().equals(userSalary)) {
                            score2 = 15;


                        }

                        if (!dataSnapshot.child("salary").getValue().toString().equals(userSalary) && dataSnapshot.child("salary").getValue().toString().equals(userex6)) {
                            score2 = 15;


                        }

                        if (dataSnapshot.child("timetofill").getValue().toString().equals(userTimevacancy)) {
                            score3 = 15;


                        }    

                        if (dataSnapshot.child("experience").getValue().toString().equals(userExperince)) {
                            score4 = 20;


                        }

                        if (!dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().equals("default")) {
                            profileImageUrl = dataSnapshot.child("profileImageUrl").getValue().toString();


                        }
                        score0 = score1 + score2 + score3 + score4;
                        mytest = String.valueOf(score0);


                        cards item = new cards(dataSnapshot.getKey(), dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString(), mytest, profileImageUrl);


                        m2.setText(mytest);
                        ratingBarset();
                        rowItems.add(item);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf("error"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Below is the rating bar method

```
public void ratingBarset() {
        String a = mytest;

        switch (a) {
            case "5":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("1.0"));
                break;
            case "10":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("1.5"));
                break;
            case "15":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("2.0"));
                break;
            case "20":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("2.5"));
                break;
            case "25":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("3.0"));
                break;
            case "30":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("3.5"));
                break;
            case "35":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("4.0"));
                break;
            case "40":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("4.5"));
                break;
            case "45":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("4.5"));
                break;
            case "50":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;
            case "55":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;
            case "60":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;
            case "65":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;
            case "70":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;
            case "75":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;
            case "80":
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("5.0"));
                break;

            default: 
                ratingBar.setRating(Float.parseFloat("0.0"));

                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the score perhaps is of the list item, right?

Comment: score is collecting  the score from all the if statements and than shows in the mytest card item .

Comment: do i have a way to put listeners to mytest  , if mytest  have listener to notify the data change on the  card , than rating bar method can run accordingly.  any comments on this idea ?